# SQL IErrorInfo.GetDescription error.Brackets not working

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net

I have the following code. I tried putting brackets around all the tables and parameters with no luck. The query works in Access though.

```
 Dim cn As OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim str As String
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader

    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()

    Try
        cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=G:\Sean\BMSBonder3_0.mdb;")
        cn.Open()
        str = "Select [Session.BonderIdentifier], [Bonder.ID], [Session.UserName], [Session.Login], [Session.Logout] From [Session] Left Join " _
        & " Bonder On  Session.Login = [Bonder.Date] Where [BasicLogin] >= ? AND [BasicLogin] <= ? AND BonderIdentifier = '?'"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Start", MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("End", MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("BID", ListBox1.SelectedItem)

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read()
            If dr.Item(0).ToString <> "" Then
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr.Item(0), dr.Item(1), dr.Item(2), dr.Item(3), dr.Item(4))

            End If
        End While
        DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns.Item("Login_Time"), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
        dr.Close()
        cn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

**Edit:**

Actual error-> IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)

Answer (score 1):

Well since no one decided to answer I found it on my own.

Seems that using session as a table name and Date as a parameter was a bad idea. I changed them and it worked.

Comment: thanks for the solution. Apparently 'diagnostics' is also table name that doesn't work.